# Endless loop in angularfire2 subscription

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am getting data and add data to the same node within an subscription. How can I avoid the endless loop?

```
this.af.database.list('objects/').subscribe(x=>{   / the subscription is only needed once
  this.af.database.list('objects/').push({newobject: ''};
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shoot me if I'm wrong, or don't, but I believe you can use the `first()` method:

```
this.af.database.list('objects/').first().subscribe(x=>{ 
  this.af.database.list('objects/').push({newobject: ''};
};
```